# Android - How to join two points using paint

Tags: android, path, draw

I want to draw a Alphabets A-Z but the alphabets should drawn in particular path.. so,i tried to co-ordinate two points and make a path between two points and using paint join two points..
But i could not able to make path between two points. can anyone tell me how to make a path and how to join two points?

Answer (score 2):

as in an actual line to connect two points?

within your canvas:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, p);
```

Comment: i tried but paint is working all over the surfaceview.. but i just want to draw in particular path that is between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)